# Java program does't work with ftp on Solaris.

Tags: java, ftp, solaris

I`ve written simple java application for working with FTP. It works fine on Windows and Linux, but hangs on Solaris. Here is the source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ftp_try {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String hlpurl = "ftp://<user>:<pass>@host/../../some_path/some_file";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(hlpurl);
        final URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        final int remoteSize = con.getContentLength();
        System.out.println("connection: " + con.toString());
        System.out.println("remote size:" + remoteSize);
        System.out.println("closing connection");
        con.getInputStream().close();
        System.out.println("connection closed");
        System.in.read();
       }
    catch ( MalformedURLException exp) {
            System.out.println("1");
       }
    catch (IOException exp) {
           System.out.println(2);
       }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that on Solaris my program hangs up after

`System.out.println("closing connection");`.

Would you help me to find out why is it happening?

PS: JDK is java 6 SE u 23

---

Update: if it would be any help for those who face the same problem. I`ve found little workaround:
read all available bytes from connection and then you can close it.
Like this:

```
byte[] buffer= new byte [con.getInputStream().available()];    
con.getInputStream().read(buffer);
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't throw an exception? Can you please post the output of accessing e.g. ftp.isc.org/robots.txt.

Comment: Yes, I`m absolutely sure it doesn`t. And about output of accessing link you provided. It`s impossible because Solaris machine doesn`t have access to Internet. The example file in my code is located in my local network. Here is output for my file, if it can be useful: connection: sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection:ftp://user:pass@host/../../path_to_file/file.txt
remote size:1290245
closing connection

Answer (score 0):

You are locking your program by reading standard input here:

```
System.out.println("connection closed");
System.in.read(); // <-- here
```

If you press any key the program will be completed

Comment: Program hangs before reading from console. "connection closed" isn`t printed at all.